# Visualizing 3 features simultaneously in Seurat/single cell RNA sequencing

Tags: bioinformatics, seurat, sequencing

I am wondering if it is possible to visualize 3 features from a single cell RNA sequencing data set simultaneously.

I use the blend function of DimPlot to visualize 2 features, but is it possible to then superimpose an additional feature to the same UMAP plot? For example, perhaps as a third color or outlined circles or some other such mechanism?

I have been struggling with this question for a while and I feel like it may require a creative solution, so I'm reaching out for some help :)

Thank you!

I tried binarizing the features, but still I can only visualize 2 features at a time. I also wonder how to binarize custom columns in the meta.data, for example, how to binarize module scores calculated from AddModuleScore or a related function.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could simply modify the metadata column you use in DimPlot to include this third feature.
Could you show us what your metadata looks like ( only the top few rows) it should make it easier for us to help you.